# DateTime arithmetic in an ActiveRecord query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two `datetime` columns in a `User`/`users` table: `created_at` and `birthdate`. I'd like to find users whose birthdate is less than 13 years before their creation date.

The equivalent Rails `if` statement would be `((created_at - birthdate) < 13.years)`

How do I translate this to an ActiveRecord query (one that'll work on PostgreSQL)? Is this even possible, or will I have to iterate over all records manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use an [interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE), then it is pretty much a straight transliteration of the Rails version:

```
User.where(%q{created_at - birthdate < interval '13 years'})
```

The difference between two timestamps (or a timestamp and a date) is an interval so you just need the appropriate value on the right side of your comparison.

Comment: That works. Thank you! A note for anyone else reading this: `interval` doesn't work on SQLite. I had to log into my production server using PostgreSQL to test it out.

Comment: @LouieGeetoo: You really shouldn't be developing and deploying on different stacks, a little syntax difference with date arithmetic is going to be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to formulate that in PostgreSQL syntax inside your where clause.

For MySQL this would look similar to this using the [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function:

```
User.where("DATEDIFF(created_at, birthdate) > (13 * 365)")
```

13*356 is there to represent 3 years in days since datediff returns difference in days.

I would then encapsulate that in a scope-like function like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Model
  def self.age_difference(years)
    where("DATEDIFF(created_at, birthdate) > (? * 365)", years)
  end
end
```

So you can call it:

```
User.age_difference(13).each do |user|
  puts user.inspect
end
```

I guess it's similar in Postgres.

Comment: You have a leap year problem.

Comment: Life is too short for leap year problems :D .. I just assumed it's not that much of an issue..

Comment: Leap years aside, it is generally accepted that there are 365 days in a year, not 356. ;) Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @LouieGeetoo: It was generally accepted that two digits were enough to hold a year...

Comment: LouiGeetoo: Ups ;) yeah that happens when you have twenty things to do but hang out on stackoverflow instead..