# Tricky Rails ActiveRecord (SQL is acceptable!) query to find a proportion of users given conditions in two join tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :rates
  ...
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :rates
  ...
end
```

I am researching whether the time a user spends on a resource is indicative of their opinion of the resource (I believe it is). Here's some more relevant data:

[image]

Now, I need to get a proportion. It is the proportion of users that upvote a resource GIVEN that they have:

1) Voted either up or down on the resource

2) Have viewed the resource for at least 5 minutes

How can I achieve this?

(will be updating this post as I continue to experiment/flounder towards the answer)

Comment: You may find this thread helpful for the view duration bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301400/datetime-arithmetic-in-an-activerecord-query-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, maybe I can at least get you a SQL query, then we can worry about ActiveRecord-izing it:

```
SELECT resources.*, sum(case views.vote when 'up' 1 else 0 end) as up_votes, count(views.id) as total_views     
  FROM resources 
  JOIN views ON views.resource_id = resources.id
  JOIN rates ON rates.resource_id = resources.id 
    AND rates.user_id = views.user_id
  WHERE views.updated_at - views.created_at >= interval '5 minutes'
  AND views.vote IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY resources.id
```

Now, I'm not completely sure this is right, of course, but it might be a start. You could then break it down into ActiveRecord form thus:

```
@resources = Resources.
  select("resources.*, sum(case views.vote when 'up' 1 else 0 end) as up_votes, count(views.id) as total_views").
  joins("JOIN views ON views.resource_id = resources.id JOIN rates ON rates.resource_id = resources.id AND rates.user_id = views.user_id").
  where("views.updated_at - views.created_at >= interval '5 minutes' AND views.vote IS NOT NULL").
  group("GROUP BY resources.id")
```

The `up_votes` and `total_views` would be attached to each Resource object, so you could call and manipulate them (I've found they get cast as strings for some reason, so you may need to use `.to_f` on 'em:

```
ratios = @resources.map{|r| r.up_votes.to_f/r.total_views.to_f}
```

You could also do the division in the `select`, if you wanted the database to sort by the ratios or some such.

If you actually just wanted the ratio over all resources, just take out the grouping (although I don't know that ActiveRecord would be involved there, except insofar as it's providing the connection to the DB).

Comment: This is helping a lot! However, I'm trying to obtain the ratio of up votes to total votes, given that the user has viewed the resource for at least 5 minutes. Your solution is helping me undo some of my mental knots on this whole ordeal though!