# Rails how to get attribute from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Model** 
Material(it has attribute arrive_date:date)

**Controller**
materials_controller,
urgent_controller

In urgent_controller I want to find out all materials which should be received within 5 days by doing this

```
class UrgentController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @materials = Material.where((Time.zone.now.to_date - arrive_date).to_i <= 5)
  end
end
```

But urgent_controller do not know this attribute and show error

> undefined local variable or method `arrive_date' for

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include code to show your controllers?  Controllers shouldn't need to know about one another.  The `urgent_controller` should have its own `arrive_date` defined, separately from `materials_controller`.

Comment: @EricWalker Hi, please see the updated code

Comment: I see.  You probably want something like what is being done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301400/datetime-arithmetic-in-an-activerecord-query-postgresql.  There will be a similar answer for MySQL.  The important point is that the `arrive_date` seems to be a column in your database, so you cannot refer to it as a Ruby method or variable.

Comment: In your case, it will probably be something like: `Material.where(%{now() - arrive_date <= interval '5 days'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should create a `scope` in your `Material` model.

```
scope :last_5_days, -> { where('arrive_date >= ?', 5.days.ago.to_date) }
```

Then call it in your controller

```
def index
  @materials = Material.last_5_days
end
```

Hope this helps.