# Rails sql query difference between two dates more then 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table that has 2 columns "date_from" and "date_to". I have to make a query which should return results where "date_to" - "date_from" == "2 weeks".

Something like this:

> `User.where('date_to - date_from == 2.weeks').`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301400/datetime-arithmetic-in-an-activerecord-query-postgresql

Comment: Do you want records with date difference more or equal 2 weeks? In title you want `more`, in question you write `==`...

Comment: I tried with interval but I didn't manage to make it work. Thought mysql maybe doesn't have same syntax or support as in that post that @AndreyDeineko linked. I need == 2 weeks.

Comment: I did exactly this:
`where(%q{date_to - date_from < interval '13 years'})`
And it is giving me error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1" which I totally don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, for mysql at least

```
User.where('1 + DATEDIFF(date_to, date_from) >= 14')
```

Comment: just `DATEDIFF(date_to, date_from) < 13` should work

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's just for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is the answer, have to test it thoroughly but its giving results which seem valid.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Comment: Btw @Ursus is the "1 + ..." here for some reason or did you just put it for funsies?

Comment: Because if you pass the same date twice to DATEDIFF the result is 0. When I use it I always want 1 in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Define this on user:

```
def self.two_weeks
   where(date_to: date_from + 2.weeks)
end
```

Then you can just call `User.two_weeks`

Can also be done as a scope, if you prefer:

```
scope :two_weeks, -> { where(date_to: date_from + 2.weeks) }
```

It's good to keep these kinds of things on the model anyway, so that you can change them in one place if they need to be tweaked

Comment: I don't have date_from variable, query must be without any params given to it.

Comment: @Choki1708 is `date_from` not an attribute on user? If it is, then it should be callable as demonstrated in my example. If not, then it's impossible to run your query without passing it in

Comment: But this way date_from is a variable. This is like doing this:
`user_id = 1
User.where(id: user_id)`
and I needed something like @Ursus. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Choki1708, when you call this query, all you need to type is `User.two_weeks` - nothing else. You don't have to declare any variables. As long as you put the method on your user model